# How can I merge two almost identical javascript objects into one using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

I have an array that contains a number of objects which are almost identical.  I want to merge these objects into one, while keeping the data that is not the same between them.

Here's my data:

```
[
  { id: 1,
    title: 'The title',
    description: 'The description',
    categories: [ 
      {id: 1, name: 'Cat 1'} 
    ] 
  }, 
  { id: 1,
    title: 'The title',
    description: 'The description',
    categories: [ 
      {id: 2, name: 'Cat 2'} 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

I want the final result to be:

```
[
  { id: 1,
    title: 'The title',
    description: 'The description',
    categories: [ 
      {id: 1, name: 'Cat 1'}, 
      {id: 2, name: 'Cat 2'} 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try the example given for [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs#mergeWith).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place there you paste a data and required result and get a solution. We here to help, not to think for you.

Comment: What is the definition of "almost identical"?

Comment: So far I've tried _.uniq, _uniqWith, _.union, _.unionWith and combos of them.  Thank you, Aristarhys for your helpful comment.  As I use Stackflow more, I hope I have the opportunity to repay the favor.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathon!  I think that will work for me.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a1 = [
  { id: 1,
    title: 'The title',
    description: 'The description',
    categories: [ 
      {id: 1, name: 'Cat 1'} 
    ] 
  }, 
  { id: 1,
    title: 'The title',
    description: 'The description',
    categories: [ 
      {id: 2, name: 'Cat 2'} 
    ] 
  } 
];
var a2 = [];

_.forEach(a1, function(item){
    if(a2.length === 0){
    a2.push(item);
  }else{
    _.forIn(item, function(value, key){
         if(!a2[0].hasOwnProperty(key)){
        a2[0][key] = value;
       }else{
            if(typeof value === "object" && value.length > 0){
            _.forEach(value, function(v){
                    console.log("Pushing Item into Categories")
                    a2[0][key].push(v);
            })
          }
       }
    })
  }

})

console.log(a2)
```

This is not the most elegant solution, however it gets the job done, and will combine any length array of "a1" into an array with length of 1 Object, and combine any nested arrays within the items it iterates over.

So, it could work on the following array as well... just for sake of example:

```
var a1 = [
  { id: 1,
    title: 'The title',
    description: 'The description',
    categories: [ 
      {id: 1, name: 'Cat 1'} 
    ],
    franks: [
        {"blaH":"blah"}
    ]
  }, 
  { id: 1,
    title: 'The title',
    description: 'The description',
    categories: [ 
      {id: 2, name: 'Cat 2'} 
    ] ,
    franks: [
        {"blaH":"blah1"}
    ]
  } ,
  { id: 1,
    title: 'The title',
    description: 'The description',
    categories: [ 
      {id: 2, name: 'Cat 2'} 
    ] ,
    franks: [
        {"blaH":"blah2"},
      {"blaH":"blah3"}
    ]
  } 
];
```

Comment: I tried different ways with the mergeWith, uniq, union, etc, and didn't get it.  This worked perfectly.  Thanks for your help, Aaron.